# Speed of jQuery .load

Tags: jquery, optimization, load

I'm using many instances of the code below to pull in content from other pages on a website:

```
$('#result').load('my-page.html #container');
```

Are there any tricks to getting this content load any quicker than normal? Load times range from 3 to 8 seconds which I would like to improve. Using .htaccess I am already caching the JS and CSS which exists on both the first page as well as 'my-page.html', as I presume the browser is loading these files on its journey to fetching the content - can this be prevented?

Comment: So you load many files via AJAX. How many? 10? 50? Each AJAX request involves a network request and the corresponding server-side processing. The jQuery processing time is almost for sure the most irrelevant bit. Have you had a look at what's going on in your debugging console's "Net" tab?

Comment: There are 15 files to be loaded sequentially. Thanks for your suggestion, the Net tab does indeed tell me that each whole page has to load. It's a CMS site so the pages being fetched include a lot of scripts/stylesheets/PHP... is there any possible way to stop the processing when the called page first loads, so it can grab the #container more efficiently? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your statement suggests that you might be loading hundreds of files including assets. There's no workaround for that apart from using server-side technologies to compose the final page.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case, but thanks for the answer.